# JavaScript: Making password to a spesefic div

Tags: javascript, passwords

I am working on something, and I don't have any codes for now, because I have no idea how to do this! Please help me out here :D

What I think would be nice is if I could make a password that changes my style:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
    .passwordProtected {
       display:none; <- this is supposed to change to "block" when the password is written in, and they click "Show div"
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="loginArea">
        <input type="password"> <--- This is where they type the password
    </div>
    <div id="passwordprotected" class="passwordProtected">
         <h1>This is the protected div they enter</h1>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

What do I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding you right, the code would look something like this:

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
    .passwordProtected {
       display:none;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="loginArea">
        <input type="password">
        <button onclick='showDiv();'>Show div</button>
    </div>
    <div id="passwordprotected" class="passwordProtected">
         <h1>This is the protected div they enter</h1>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function showDiv(){
      var myDiv = document.querySelector('.passwordProtected');
       myDiv.style.display = 'block';
     }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

You can find out more about styling with JavaScript here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_style.asp.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for late answer! But this has no password the people will have to type in! So this will not work :D